# get a ClassCastException inJmsSpout when setting MessageTimeoutSecs in topology main method

Tags: java, apache-storm

I set the MessageTimeoutSecs para in topology main method.

```
 Config conf = new Config();      
 conf.setMessageTimeoutSecs(200); //this is a int 
 StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[0], conf, builder.createTopology());
```

But I get a cast error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at backtype.storm.contrib.jms.spout.JmsSpout.open(JmsSpout.java:160) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__6579$fn__6594.invoke(executor.clj:522) ~[storm-core-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__459.invoke(util.clj:461) ~[storm-core-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_22]
```

The JmsSpout code is :

```
Integer topologyTimeout = (Integer)conf.get("topology.message.timeout.secs");
// TODO fine a way to get the default timeout from storm, so we're not hard-coding to 30 seconds (it could change)
topologyTimeout = topologyTimeout == null ? 30 : topologyTimeout;
```

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Storm converts the timeout value into a `long` internally. Not sure why. To resolve this, you need to cast to `Long`  (and convert to `Integer` or `int` afterwards if you need an integer).

```
Object timeout = conf.get("topology.message.timeout.secs");
Integer topologyTimeout = timeout == null ? 30 : ((Long)timeout).intValue;
```

Comment: But this JmsSpout is a class provided by storm itself. is there any way else?

Comment: I see... You could try to set the timeout globally in `storm.yaml` (if this is an option for you and does not mess with other Topologies). Can you report this to the mailing list? Sounds like a bug to me.